# Не могу продублировать регистрацию в системе странице сайта на другую странцу

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Ребят, ситуация такая... Есть платежная система, установленная на сайте:

```
conv-service.ru/epay/inde...
```

В ней отлично проходит и регистрация и логин. Но написана она не просто на `<form action="file.php">`

Не могу сделать так, чтобы на сайте `conv-service.ru` все проходило, как будто это оформляется с родных страничек `conv-service.ru/epay/inde...`, а именно:

Процесс Как регистрируемся:

- человек заполняет поля `joxi.ru/Vm65a6OClyxDrZ`;
- жмет на кнопку `joxi.ru/Q2KDe5RIPN9yAj`;
- если нет ошибок ему говорят, что "вы зарегистрироаны, идите на мыло" (попап либо текстом рядом с формой);
- человек более на этой странице ничего не ловит и идет на свое мыло, переходить по по ссылке в письме;
- а т. к. эта ссылка будет кидать его на саму систему `conv-service.ru/epay/memb...` говоря, что почта наштяк подтверждена, он в любом случае остается внутри платежки;

Процесс Как логинимся:

- человек нажимает кнопку `joxi.ru/12M7eWOsPv49rJ`;
- всплывает попап `joxi.ru/MAj7z3yslzvqre`;
- он его заполняет и жмет на кнопку `joxi.ru/RmzKY90I4pW42O`;
- если все нормально, он попадает сразу в платежку `joxi.ru/J2bN46RF73Xx26`;

У меня есть 1 вариант - продублировать скрипт на работу с другой сраницей (ведь база то одна) и регить людей там, но я не знаю, нормально ли это и не сломается ли общая логика работы системы.

Comment: Вы можете вставлять изображения в текст вопроса средствами движка сайта. Используйте эту возможность.

Comment: У меня не открываются изображения из-за настроек безопасности на рабочем месте...